# Usage of TextField Causes NochSuchFieldError

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Simply adding a `TextField` to a composable in Android causes a `NoSuchFieldError` when executing. The application works perfectly fine when I remove the `TextField` (the application does not contain another `TextField` so far).

I think it might be a dependency issue (hence the dependencies below). But I am at my wits end. What is happening?

I have already tried to invalidate cache and restart, as well as clean and rebuild the application.

**Code:**

```kotlin
TextField(
    value = "text",
        onValueChange = {

    }
)
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field $stable of type I in class Landroidx/compose/foundation/text/KeyboardActions; or its superclasses (declaration of 'androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions' appears in /data/app/~~uEpWT9N7xCnbk8jjsQk_yg==/xx.xxx.xxx.dev-Q5085dpAd5iQ0tK6W7b8rA==/base.apk)
        at androidx.compose.material.TextFieldKt.TextField(TextField.kt:207)
```

**Dependencies:**

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.3.3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.3.3"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'

    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-common-ktx:3.1.1'
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha17"

    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.29.0-alpha"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.lets-plot:lets-plot-kotlin:3.0.0"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:5.8.1'
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.13.4"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.3"

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.2.0"
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose:3.2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your accompanist version does not match the compose UI version.
As you can see in [this page](https://google.github.io/accompanist/), if you use compose UI 1.3.X you should use accompanist 0.28.0